# getManager causes an error, getEntityManager works fine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository

As a newbie in Symfony2 & doctrine i'm struggling (in a custom repository class) with the difference between `getEntityManager()` and `getManager()`.

I know `getEntityManager()` is being deprecated but if I use `getManager()` instead, I'm getting *"Undefined method 'getManager'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!"*

In my class, the following code works:

```
public function haalidop($verbid)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery('SELECT p FROM myBundle:Verbs p WHERE p.verbid='.$verbid)
                ->getSingleResult();
}
```

If I change (upgrade?) it like the code below, I get the error...

```
public function haalidop($verbid)
    {
        return $this->getManager()
                    ->createQuery('SELECT p FROM myBundle:Verbs p WHERE p.verbid='.$verbid)
                    ->getSingleResult();
    }
```

Anyone any suggestion what's wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `getEntityManager` method of the *`Registry`* is deprecated. Since you're in a Repository, you extended not the Registry but the *`EntityRepository`*. That class has only a `getEntityManager` method, which isn't deprecated.

The reason for this inconsistency is quite easy: The Registry is something that's used for other Doctrine library too, like their ODMs. They don't use the name "Entity", but "Document". For that reason, using `getEntityManager` didn't make much sense for ODMs, that's why they changed if to `getManager`.
On the other hand, the `EntityRepository` -as its name already tells us- is ORM specific, meaning there is no confusing for ODM users (they use another repository class).

Comment: Good explanation. It finally makes sense to me.

Comment: Ok, nice comment, thanks!
Maybe this can be improved at the Symfony2 debug toolbar.  If you you getEntityManager() it always says: 'DEPRECATION - getEntityManager is deprecated since Symfony 2.1. Use getManager instead'

Comment: @PBR are you sure it's this code the debug toolbar is talking about? Those deprecation are only catched if a E_USER_DEPRECATED error is triggered, this isn't the case with the Repository#getEntityManager method.

Comment: Yes @WouterJ, you are right again, this was indeed triggered for another piece of code.  So, no problem for Symfony.  Sorry :-)

Comment: Truth lives in the [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#229-235)

Answer (score 1):

The `getEntityManager` method is still valid in repositories as you can see in the [current docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#280). It is deprecated in Controllers though and the `getManager` method should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm'
import { InjectDataSource } from "@nestjs/typeorm"; 

export class TenantsConsumer {

    constructor(
         @InjectDataSource() private readonly datasource : DataSource
    ){}

    public async promote(tenant: Tenanats){
       await this.datasource.query(
             `CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "${tenant.db}"`
           );
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

if in a controller:

```
$this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
```

if in a service:

```
$this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
```

Comment: Please, do not advocate injecting the container in a service, only inject the services you need in a service.

Comment: @WouterJ , exactly how much more costly is it to have the container injected?

Comment: it's not about time, it's about architecture. Injecting the container makes dependeny injection useless. In fact, it is called the Service Locator antipattern. Try to google for it, you find many explainations why you should avoid that pattern.